# How to include a field in search_fields if the model is inline in wagtail

Tags: django, inheritance, wagtail

I am trying to include a field in search say class BaseClass and I want to search a field in class Subclass which is inherited from class Orderable and ParentalKey with BaseClass how to add the field of subclass in search_field

```
class BaseClass(Page):
    header = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True)
    search_fields = Page.search_fields + [
        index.SearchField('title', partial_match=True)]

class SubClass(Orderable):
    article = ParentalKey('BaseClass',on_delete=models.CASCADE,
    related_name='article_description')
    body = RichTextUploadingField(_('Body'), blank=True)
```

Comment: From reading the docs (but I've never done it, hence a comment rather than an answer), it looks like you would have to make your `SubClass` inherit from `wagtail.search.index.Indexed` for it to be it is indexable and then use a `wagtail.search.index.RelatedFields` in the `search_fields` of your `BaseClass` definition. See [relevant docs section](https://docs.wagtail.io/en/v2.4/topics/search/indexing.html#index-relatedfields).